# copiar registro de tabla a otra ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo la siguiente funcion la cual recibe como parametro un id:

```
function terminar_tramite(ids) {

    var ID = ids;
    console.log(ID);
    $.ajax({
        url: "lib/controladores/tramite_terminado.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: `idss=${ID}`,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
               console.log("no está guardando")
                UIkit.notification({
                    message: 'Ocurrió un error!',
                    status: 'primary',
                    pos: 'top-right',
                    timeout: 5000
                });
            }else{
                UIkit.notification({
                    message: 'Tramite Guardado!',
                    status: 'success',
                    pos: 'bottom-center',
                    timeout: 5000
                });
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href = `?sub=adm&op=tablero_tramites`;
                },2000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                location.href = `?sub=adm&op=tablero_tramites`;
                },2000);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Mi codigo PHP:**

```
    <?php
    include '../../config.php';
    $dbserver = DB_SERVER;
    $dbuser = DB_USER;
    $password = DB_PASS;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;
    $database = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $password, $dbname);
    $variable = $_POST['idss'];
    var_dump($variable);
    if($database->connect_errno) {
        die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
    }
    $insertquery  = " INSERT INTO tramites_atendidos SELECT * FROM tramites WHERE tr_id = '$variable'";
    $jsondata = array();
    if($database->query($insertquery)){
    }
    else {  
    }
    $database->close();
?>
```

Solo que no recibe el id o no sabria si lo estoy agregando correctamente en mi Query porque si le pongo el id directamente si copia el registro

Comment: Intenta remover/comentar esta linea `processData: false`, y pasa el data como un json `data: {idss: ID}`

Comment: tampoco @KacosPro

Comment: ¿Ni pasando el data como un json?

Comment: lo intenté así `data: {
   "idss": ID
},` sin resultado exitoso

Comment: Hola, me parece que hay un problema con tu sql, digo, ids se me hace que implica que tenes una lista de varios id, mientras que en el sql usas el comparador = que es para comparardos valor, en lugar del IN que es para saber si un valor esta en una lista

Comment: Tengo un botón que envia como parametro un id cuando le doy click(solo uno) @Sacha

Comment: asi es amigo @KacosPro ese era el detalle, Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo corrige un poco la sintaxis al enviar el dato del id:

```
function terminar_tramite(ids) {

    var ID = ids;
    console.log(ID);
    $.ajax({
        url: "lib/controladores/tramite_terminado.php",
        method:'POST',
        data: {"idss": ID}, //Cambiar esta linea
       //contentType: false, -> Eliminar
       //processData: false, -> Eliminar
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
               console.log("no está guardando")
                UIkit.notification({
                    message: 'Ocurrió un error!',
                    status: 'primary',
                    pos: 'top-right',
                    timeout: 5000
                });
            }else{
                UIkit.notification({
                    message: 'Tramite Guardado!',
                    status: 'success',
                    pos: 'bottom-center',
                    timeout: 5000
                });
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href = `?sub=adm&op=tablero_tramites`;
                },2000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                location.href = `?sub=adm&op=tablero_tramites`;
                },2000);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: y en el php quedaria así : `$_POST['ID']` ??

Comment: Si, si lo mandas como ID, si lo mandas asi: data: {"idss": ID} lo recibes igual como lo tienes

Comment: no funciona ni de una forma ni de otra

Comment: Cuando imprimes con el console.log tu ID si muestra un valor?

Comment: así es me muestra el valor correcto del id, obviamente es un entero no se si lo esté agregando mal en el query o si realmente si llegue a mi archivo PHP el valor

Comment: Cambia donde colocas type: 'POST' por method:"post" en el ajax, o mejor ya edito mi respuesta

Comment: tampoco, no se si habrá alguna manera de mostrar la variable de mi PHP para verificar si llega el valor

Comment: Imprimelo en tu php con var_dump($_POST) la variable post entera;

Comment: con ` var_dump($variable);` me aparece NULL y con echo pues no me muestra nada

Comment: y con var_dump($_POST);  que te muestra?

Comment: con var_dump($_POST) me aparece NULL

Comment: Prueba eliminando  contentType: false,
        processData: false,

Comment: Muy bien amigo solo elimino contentType: false, processData: false, muchas gracias

Comment: Te funciono? Si te funciono puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: si funciono, habria que editar su respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando el envío de la variable en tu data de esta forma:

```
data: {
   "idss": ID
},
```

Comment: ya probé de las dos formas que comentan y con ninguna funciona